# Select sum(round(colum,2)) in Microsoft Dynamics x++

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I would like to ask if exist somehow the native round sql function in X++

For example I would like to do something like this

```
Select sum(round(colum,2)) from salesLine........
```

I have a feeling that I am not able to do this with a simple select but only with while Select....with a normal round inside the brackets but I think is a "slow" solution..

Best Regards,
Nikos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You'll have to do this with a `while select`.

You could do `select sum(column) from salesLine...` then round the `salesLine.column` value, but that's not technically the same as what you've written, because that does the rounding after the `sum()` where I think you're rounding before the `sum()`.

Comment: Also note that AX uses its own rounding logic in different places, which may behave differently than the SQL rounding. This may introduce data inconsistency in your system.

Comment: If you can accept the SQL rounding functions, you may be able do the trick using view computed field described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845841.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396